# Ubuntu 18.04lts - several problems - high compiz CPU, HDMI port not working, etc

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, compiz, hdmi, workspaces

So these problems have been occurring for a while, but I have been far too busy to do anything until now. After I updated from Ubuntu 16.04 lts to 18.04 lts these things all started. Here are a list of the problems I have seen, I am sure there are probably more;

1) the CPU skyrockets from compiz. Just doing nothing and it can be over 100%.

2) the HDMI port does not work. I have tried several monitors and cables. Nothing changes. When I open systems settings and click on desktop settings, the window crashes.

3. For some reason I cannot use any hotkeys to switch workspaces. I expect this is an easy fix but I also think they are all connected...

comp info (some)
Kernel: 4.15.0-34-generic x86_64
           bits: 64 gcc: 7.3.0
           Desktop: Gnome 3.28.3 (Gtk 3.22.30-1ubuntu1)
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: System76 product: Oryx Pro v: oryp3 
           Mobo: System76 model: Oryx Pro v: oryp3 serial: N/A
           UEFI: American Megatrends v: 1.05.03RSA1 date: 02/16/2017
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile]

I am considering another distro, but we will see.

Lastly, I probably forgot to say something but I cannot remember everything so if you need more information just ask me.

Comment: `pavucontrol` may help for HDMI issue

Comment: Ok so I fixed part of the second problem with; sudo apt-get install system76-driver-nvidia
I still cannot open desktop sharing in system settings or change the hotkeys for changing the workspace...

Comment: @Pycnopodia Desktop sharing is a known bug. Merge requests is still pending. Also Upgrading from 16.04 won't work. Try a fresh install. For me compiz cpu usage is minimal.